# Amazon EC2 - how to get list of process running on instances via AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

How to get a list of process running on Amazon EC2 instances via the AWS API?

Answer (score 3):

This could be accomplished by using the [Amazon EC2 Systems Manager Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which uses an agent installed on EC2 instances to run remote commands.

It takes a bit of configuration, but allows you to run commands on potentially hundreds of instances with one command.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The EC2 API doesn't provide any actions to perform operations or retrieve data from the operating system layer.

Comment: **In principle**, you're absolutely correct. The EC2 infrastructure has no visibility into what's running on an instance... but AWS does have a relatively new optional agent daemon that can be installed that allows commands to be run on instances (and output fetched) via the API.